# Unexpected '}' in R-script, can't figure out why?

Tags: r

r-studio keeps telling me that there is a unexpected '}' in my code, but can't see why. I already checked every bracket twice...

```
    for (i in 1:100){
        for(j in 1:15){
            if (s2[i] == sensoren[j,1] && s3[i] == sensoren[j,2] && s4[i] ==   sensoren[j,3]){ 
                print(sensoren[j,5])
                i <- i + 1
                } else              
                j <- j + 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code you posted above has valid syntax. You're not giving us the full story.

Comment: The rest of the code are just some assignments and look like that: 


sensoren <- read.csv("C:/Users/blub.csv") 
messung <- read.table("C:/Users/bla.log")
s1 <- messung$V2
s2 <- messung$V4
s3 <- messung$V6
s4 <- messung$V8

Comment: post a complete reproducible example.

Comment: or the full log, including where the statement starts with a `>` on the left and all the way down to the error.

Comment: Rstudio probably also tells you which line in you code contains the error.

Comment: Does it have those plus signs in it?

Comment: @User2351938 Welcome to SO.  When you post code please remove the beginning `+` and `>` signs that print to the console.  This forces a small but unnecessary burden onto those helping you.

Answer (score 2):

Using (since you didn't give us data; this is considered unkind):

```
s2 <- s3 <- s4 <- 1:100
sensoren <- mtcars

## > for (i in 1:100){
## +        for(j in 1:15){
## +            if (s2[i] == sensoren[j,1] && s3[i] == sensoren[j,2] && s4[i] ==   sensoren[j,3]){ 
## +                print(sensoren[j,5])
## +                i <- i + 1
## +                } else             
## +                j <- j + 1
## +        }
## +     }
## > }
## Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

## And then:

## > for (i in 1:100){
## +        for(j in 1:15){
## +            if (s2[i] == sensoren[j,1] && s3[i] == sensoren[j,2] && s4[i] ==   sensoren[j,3]){ 
## +                print(sensoren[j,5])
## +                i <- i + 1
## +                } else {            
## +                j <- j + 1
## +        }
## +     }
## + }
```

Try a `{` after the `else`

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly because your full code has an unbalanced "("  or "[" somewhere, so the "}" is seen in an illegal location.